# Conditional Operator vs if else

Tags: c, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

Can we use multiple lines of statements inside the true section of conditional operator like in if else?

```
(a>b)? large = a; printf("%d",a) : large = b; printf("%d",b);
```

Can we use multiple line if statements in the true section of a ternary operator??

Comment: The conditional expression is an *expression*, and can only contain other expressions, not statements.

Comment: As a workaround, why not separate it into two statements, like `int large = a > b ? a : b; printf("%d\n", large);`. It also have the good thing that it's readable and easy to understand.

Comment: ... which is less repetitive anyway.

Comment: Side note: style guides for C typically recommend limiting the use of ternary expressions or even avoiding them altogether.  If ever you're uncertain whether to use a ternary expression or an `if` / `else` statement, choose the latter.

Comment: As a general rule, you should avoid putting too many things in a single statement anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You can but it is a terrible idea:

- it is hard to read (generally almost all comma separated expressions are)
- ternary operator was not invented for this purpose - basically to get value depending on condition.

```
large = (a > b) ? (printf("%d\n", a), a) : (printf("%d\n", b), b);
```

Instead of this monster you can simply:

```
large = (a > b) ? a : b;
printf("%d\n", large);
```

Comment: You can also inline the actual value instead, as in `printf("%d", (a > b) ? a : b);`

Comment: *it is hard to read (generally almost all comma separated expressions are)*  Too true.  Where's the brain bleach to clear this out of my mind?!?!  ;-)  It's also a [non-portable GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html).

Comment: @RobertHarvey you forgot abot `large`. If you add it to the printf it will be same terrible as an original one.

Comment: @AndrewHenle This is standard C, no statement expression is involved.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by using ,(comma) to separate expressions

```
(a > b) ? (large = a, printf("%d", a)) : (large = b, printf("%d", b));
```

Comment: And what would the result of this ternary be? What are you assigning it to, since it cannot be a standalone statement?

Comment: @Rogue It doesn't need to be assigned. This is a strange one-liner, not recommend style, but valid C none the less.

Comment: That's indeed a strange one liner and I hate it. +1. That said, it's almost always more succinct to use that ternary for assignment/production of a value (e.g. `large = a > b ? a : b`, or combining the printf into the terms via `large = a > b ? (printf(...), a) : (printf(...), b)`). Worded differently, doing the assignment inside the ternary is a smell that something's inside-out.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional operator is... an operator, and as such subject to the syntax rules of operators and expressions just like any other operator.

To include multiple sub-expressions in the same expression, we may use the `,` comma operator, which has left-to-right evaluation and returns the result of the right operand.

What you probably meant to do is something like this:

```
large = (a > b) ? (printf("%d\n",a), a) : (printf("%d\n",b), b);
```

Here we may note:

- Operator precedence goes as `>` before `?:` before `=` before `,` (the comma operator).
- Therefore the parenthesis around `(a > b)` isn't actually necessary but makes the code more readable.
- Since `?:` has higher precedence than `=` we need not wrap the whole `?:` in a parenthesis.
- But since `,` has lower precedence than `?:`, we must use inner parenthesis or we will get very strange results.

  For example if `b>a` and we have no parenthesis for the 3rd operator, then the `printf` statement will get taken as the result to be assigned and `large` will contain the return value of `printf` rather than `b` as expected.
- This code is rather silly because we might as well write `large = (a > b) ? a : b;` and then print `large`. Way more readable.
- This is an unreadable mess in general. We should avoid excessive use of the `?:` and `,` operators since they tend to make code less readable. Their main usage is the niche topic of implementing function-like macros (which in itself should be avoided when possible). Using an `if`/`else` is almost always the preferred version.

Comment: `?:` is typically used for inlining certain small operations, especially during output.  For example: `printf(value < 0 ? "(%f)" : "%f"), abs(value));`

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple expressions inside the conditional operator branches using the comma operator, yet except in very specific circumstances, it is considered bad style, a form of code obfuscation:

```
    (a > b) ? (large = a, printf("%d", a)) : (large = b, printf("%d", b));
```

The value of the full expression is the return value of the `printf` call from the selected branch.  Ignoring this value might let the compiler produce a warning.

Note that if `large` is defined as an `int`, this expression can simplified as:

```
    printf("%d", large = a > b ? a : b);
```

Still there is no reason to hide the side effect inside the `printf` argument. This is much more readable:

```
    large = a > b ? a : b;  // or better: large = max(a, b);
    printf("%d", large);
```